# Add 2 ints and compare to a float

Tags: java, math, floating-point

I have 2 numbers:

```
int LIMIT1 = 20;    
int LIMIT2 = 10;  


int a, b;  
float c;
```

The threshold is defined as `final float threshold= Math.round(a * b / c)`
The following code works:

```
if(threshold < (float) (LIMIT1 + LIMIT2)) {  
//code  
}
```

Is this the best way to compare this?

Comment: You don't need to cast. The `int` will be promoted before making the comparison.

Comment: It can be improved by spelling variable names correctly.

Comment: How about `if(threshold < LIMIT1 + LIMIT2) `  or `LIMIT = LIMIT1 + LIMIT2;  if(threshold < LIMIT) ...`

Comment: "best" probably depends on the context but this seems to be at least a reasonable way to do it. What makes you doubt your solution is usable/correct?

Comment: @Thomas: Because is only equality of floats problematic then?

Comment: and by best way to compare you mean fastest way to compare or something else ?

Comment: @Jim you're confusing with float (im)precision.

Comment: @Jim Since floats can express a range of (small) integers exactly, even a test for equality between int and float is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @Jim you refer to precision issues, don't you? Ofc this can be a problem but in most cases it manifests when using really huge or small (very near to 0) values or calculations. Comparing a resonably sized value for `treshold` which probably is set via some literal and an integer should normally not be a problem, e.g. if `threshold` was 30.0f it would probably be equal to `LIMIT1 + LIMIT2`. If threshold was somehow calculated though, you _might_ end up with a value close to but not exactly 30.0 (something like 29.9999 or 30.0001).

Comment: @Thomas:It is calcualted from `Math.round` so I could end up in what you point out

Comment: You might provide those details in your question then.

Comment: @Thomas: I updated OP

Comment: @Jim `Math.round()` already rounds to an `int` value so you might want to consider defining `threshold` as `int` instead of `float`. Besides that even using float shouldn't result in any issues with values as small as yours. The only thing I'd not like about this is that `threshold` seems to always hold an integer value and using float here implies something something else - it's more a readability/style issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused with another situation. If you are comparing two floats for equality you might want to get the absolute of the difference and compare that to some small epsilon value.

```
// Define this once for your project.
// Change the value depending on the accuracy you want.
static final float EPSILON = 0.0001f;
...

if (Math.abs(f1 - f2) < EPSILON) { 
    ...
```

However in your case; you only check to see if one float is greater than another number. So I believe you're fine with what you have apart from the unnecessary cast.

```
if(threshold < LIMIT1 + LIMIT2)
```